# Cannot ping two hosts from different subnet with Cisco routers

Tags: router, ping

I have a configuration where two Cisco routers are in different subnets. The first one is in 192.168.0.0/24 and the second one is in 192.168.1.0/24. The routers are connected via serial by the 192.168.2.0/30.

My problem is that I cannot ping computers from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24. I set a static route to 192.168.2.0/30 in order to make all traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 go to serial's router.

Comment: Which Cisco routers did you use? If the serial line mean to transfer data or it is a console port? Can you show up the routing tables on the ciscos (on both of them).

Comment: you need two routes for this to work, one in each direction

Comment: @wmz I have two routers
@Hennes I dont have right know the table routes, but I remember the commands:
on interface f0/0 `ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0`
on interface s0/0 `ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.252`
on config t `ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.252 s0/0`
and that's all I do on one router, same in the other but with different ip address, the routers are cisco router 1700

Comment: No - two `routes` - two route entries, one on each router. And the ones you have are wrong (redundant) - router already knows how to route to network on a directly connected interface, no need to tell it that. You need to define how to reach networks .0.0 and .1.0. One entry per router.

Comment: Please post copy-pasted output of `ifconfig` and `route` (or equivalent) for each router, so it will be possible to tell what's wrong. Router model might be useful too.

Comment: @wmz so, what I had to do is `ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 s0/0` in order to tell the router that subnet 192.168.1.0 send traffic through interface s0/0??, I cannot get the show output right now...

Comment: yes, but it means:  tell the router that anything that goes to 192.68.0.0 should be sent to int s0/0.

Comment: @wmz Well, I have done the configuration that you say and everything works perfect, thanks for the explanation, I tried to answer my own question but I couldn't, anyway thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this, was setting the static route to the other network:

in the first router I have this:

```
interface f0/0 ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0
interface s0/0 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.252
ip route ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

in the second router I have this:

```
interface f0/0 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
interface s0/0 ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.252
ip route ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

I have done this wrong cause I put the static route like this:

`ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.252`

Thanks to @wmz that tell me the right way to do this